# htaccess htpasswd not work

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, .htpasswd

I have configured `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` to cpanel.

When I change some documents on cpanels it seems there is no response.

There is no small window to ask for username and password.

The content of `.htpasswd` is `Adelaide:AU.MWWN07rEfU`

[image: the path of both files]

[image: content of .htpasswd1]

[image: content of my .htaccess file]

Comment: content of .htpasswd is Adelaide:AU.MWWN07rEfU